# how does javascript move to a specific index in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is more a general question about the inner workings of the language. I was wondering how javascript gets the value of an index. For example when you write  `array[index]` does it loop through the array till it finds it? or by some other means? the reason I ask is because I have written some code where I am looping through arrays to match values and find points on a grid, I am wondering if performance would be increased by creating and array like `array[gridX][gridY]` or if it will make a difference. what I am doing now is going through a flat array of objects with gridpoints as properties like this:

```
var array = [{x:1,y:3}];
```

then looping through and using those coordinates within the object properties to identify and use the values contained in the object.

my thought is that by implementing a multidimensional grid it would access them more directly as can specify a gridpoint by saying `array[1][3]` instead of looping through and doing:

```
for ( var a = 0; a < array.length; a += 1 ){
    if( array[a].x === 1 && array[a].y === 3 ){
        return array[a];
    }
}
```

or something of the like.

any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You cannot use gridpoints as properties. Property names need to be strings (and on an array, integers)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. in the case that I am illustrating, the numbers represent points an a grid, and anything within the array would be drawn, deleted, moved to the grid points... so.. if I wanted to say that there is a dot at grid points { x:3, y:5} I could say:

Comment: I say that `array[{x:1,y:3}]` won't work. `array["{x:1,y:3}"]` would work, but is unnecessarily complicated. `array["1,3"]` or `array[1][3]` it should be.

Comment: `array[{x:1,y:3}]` has been working... the array contains objects, the object property name is x and the value is 1

Comment: You mean you've used `array = [{x:1,y:3}]` and then `array[0]` to access the object. But using `array[{x:1,y:3}]` does not work to access properties.

Comment: oh.. yeah, i meant `array = [{x:1,y:3}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it's an array or an object, the underlying structure in any modern javascript engine is a hashtable.  Need to prove it?  Allocate an array of 1000000000 elements and notice the speed and lack of memory growth.  Javascript arrays are a special case of Object that provides a `length` method and restricts the keys to integers, but it's sparse.

So, you are really chaining hashtables together.  When you nest tables, as in `a[x][y]`, you creating multiple hashtables, and it will require multiple visits to resolve an object.

But which is faster?  Here is a jsperf testing the speed of allocation and access, respectively:

http://jsperf.com/hash-tables-2d-versus-1d

http://jsperf.com/hash-tables-2d-versus-1d/2

On my machines, the nested approach is faster.

Intuition is no match for the profiler.

**Update:** It was pointed out that in some limited instances, arrays really are arrays underneath.  But since arrays are specialized objects, you'll find that in these same instances, objects are implemented as arrays as well (i.e., `{0:'hello', 1:'world'}` is internally implemented as an array.  But this shouldn't frighten you from using arrays with trillions of elements, because that special case will be discarded once it no longer makes sense.

Comment: No. Modern javascript engines do use arrays for arrays.

Comment: @Bergi Provide proof or citation, please.

Comment: http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation is the first that google could find. Check the last paragraph on numeric properties.

Comment: @Bergi that's misleading.  A contiguous array can be used for elements or primitive values.  The moment you access the millionth item, you become a hash map.  However, it's a good point -- for small arrays that are accessed in a specific pattern, arrays are used underneath.  But that certainly won't be the case for the OP.

Comment: Especially if you have an array of a million items, it will pay out that they are stored in an array instead of a hash map. Those arrays will grow dynamically! Of course, sparse arrays (with only one item at index 1000 000000) will fall back to hash maps.

Answer (score 2):

> For example when you write array[index] does it loop through the array till it finds it? or by some other means?

This is implementation defined. Javascript can have both numeric and string keys and the very first Javascript implementations did do this slow looping to access things.

However, nowadays most browsers are more efficient and store arrays in two parts, a packed array for numeric indexes and a hash table for the rest. This means that accessing a numeric index (for dense arrays without holes) is O(1) and accessing string keys and sparse arrays is done via hash tables.

> I am wondering if performance would be increased by creating and array like array[gridX][gridY] or if it will make a difference. what I am doing now is going through a flat array of objects with gridpoints as properties like this `array[{x:1,y:3}]`

Go with the 2 dimension array. Its a much simpler solution and is most likely going to be efficient enough for you.

Another reason to do this is that when you use an object as an array index what actually happens is that the object is converted to a string and then that string is used as a hash table key. So `array[{x:1,y:3}]` is actually `array["[object Object]"]`. If you really wanted, you could override the toString method so not all grid points serialize to the same value, but I don't think its worth the trouble.

Comment: the reason i am concerned about performance is that this is a game that I am developing, any processing overhead I can reduce is important. my dilemma is whether its worth it to go through and restructure around 3000 lines of code to accommodate a new way of processing the grid ( if more efficient could improve performance for every time the grid is accessed ) or whether the multidimensional array would increase performance at all, if not id just assume leave it how it is... furthermore to clarify, the array actually looks like `array = [{x:value,y:value}]` and accessed via last code snippet

Comment: If you really care about performance then you should be measuring things. Its impossible to solve performance problems without benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question, in JavaScript, arrays are nothing more than a specialized type of object.  If you set up an new Array like this:

```
 var someArray = new Array(1, 2, 3);
```

You end up with an `Array` object with a structure that looks more-or-less, like this (**Note:** this is strictly in regards to the data that it is storing . . . there is a **LOT** more to an `Array` object):

```
someArray = {
    0: 1,
    1: 2,
    2: 3
}
```

What the `Array` object does add to the equation, though, is built in operations that allow you to interact with it in the `[1, 2, 3]` concept that you are used to.  `push()` for example, will use the array's `length` property to figure out where the next value should be added, creates the value in that position, and increments the `length` property.

However (getting back to the original question), there is nothing in the array structure that is any different when it comes to accessing the values that it stores than any other property.  There is no inherent looping or anything like that . . . accessing `someArray[0]` is essentially the same as accessing `someArray.length`.

In fact, the only reason that you have to access standard array values using the `someArray[N]` format is that, the stored array values are number-indexed, and you cannot directly access object properties that begin with a number using the "dot" technique (i.e., `someArray.0` is invalid, `someArray[0]` is not).

---

Now, admittedly, that is a pretty simplistic view of the `Array` object in JavaScript, but, for the purposes of your question, it should be enough.  If you want to know more about the inner workings, there is TONS of information to be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: so what I am gathering as that switching to a multidimensional array structure will not increase performance over how I am currently processing the grid?

Comment: As far as the "behind-the-scenes" mechanics of accessing data goes, no.  Where you might be able to see some improvement (depending on how you use values) would be in more efficient programming logic, due the inherent indexing that arrays provide, that custom objects do not.

Answer (score 0):

single dimension hash table with direct access:

```
var array = {
    x1y3: 999,
    x10y100: 0
};
function getValue(x, y) {
    return array['x' + x + 'y' + y];
}
```